# Jest TypeError: is not a constructor in Jest.mock

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest, jest-fetch-mock

I am trying to write a unit test case using jest and need to mock the below pattern . I am getting TypeError: is not a constructor.

Usecase :  My usecase is as mentioned below

MyComponent.js :

```
 import serviceRegistry from "external/serviceRegistry";


        serviceRegistry.getService("modulename", "servvice").then(
              service => {
                let myServiceInstance = new service();
                myServiceInstance.init(p,d) 
        })
```

Mycomponent.spec.js

```
jest.mock('external/serviceRegistry', () => {
      return {
        getService: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({
          service: jest.fn().mockImplementation((properties, data, contribs) => {
            return {
              init: jest.fn(),
              util: jest.fn(),
              aspect: jest.fn()

            };
          })
        }))
      };
    }, {virtual: true});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Promise` returned by `getService` is resolving to an `object` with a `service` prop set to your constructor mock, but your code is expecting it to resolve directly to your constructor mock.

Change your `external/serviceRegistry` mock to this and it should work:

```
jest.mock('external/serviceRegistry', () => {
  return {
    getService: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(
      jest.fn().mockImplementation((properties, data, contribs) => {
        return {
          init: jest.fn(),
          util: jest.fn(),
          aspect: jest.fn()
        };
      })
    ))
  };
}, {virtual: true});
```