# ES6 imports and 'is not a constructor' in Jest.mock

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

Similar to [Jest TypeError: is not a constructor in Jest.mock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54807916/jest-typeerror-is-not-a-constructor-in-jest-mock), except I am using ES6 imports - and the answer given to that question is not working on my situation.

Following [the Jest `.mock()` documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) I am attempting to mock the constructor `Client` from the `pg` module.

I have a constructor, `Client`, imported from an ES6 module called `pg`. Instances of `Client` should have a `query` method.

```
import { Client } from "pg";
new Client({ connectionString: 'postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/database' });

export async function doThing(client): Promise<string[]> {
  var first = await client.query('wooo')
  var second = await client.query('wooo')
  return [first, second]
}
```

Here's my `__tests__/test.ts`

```
const log = console.log.bind(console)

jest.mock("pg", () => {
  return {
    query: jest
      .fn()
      .mockReturnValueOnce('one')
      .mockReturnValueOnce('two'),
  };
});

import { Client } from "pg";
import { doThing } from "../index";

it("works", async () => {
  let client = new Client({});
  var result = await doThing(client);
  expect(result).toBe(['one', 'two'])
});
```

This is similar to the answer given in [Jest TypeError: is not a constructor in Jest.mock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54807916/jest-typeerror-is-not-a-constructor-in-jest-mock), but it's failing here.

The code, just:

`const mockDbClient = new Client({ connectionString: env.DATABASE_URL });`

fails with:

`TypeError: pg_1.Client is not a constructor`

I note [the docs mention `__esModule: true` is required when using default exports](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options), but `Client` is not a default export from `pg` (I've checked).

**How can I make the constructor work properly?**

### Some additional notes after getting an answer

Here's a slightly longer-form version of the answer, with comments about what's happening on each line - I hope people reading this find it useful!

```
jest.mock("pg", () => {
  // Return the fake constructor function we are importing
  return {
    Client: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      // The consturctor function returns various fake methods
      return {
        query: jest.fn()
          .mockReturnValueOnce(firstResponse)
          .mockReturnValueOnce(secondResponse),
        connect: jest.fn()
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you mock the module, it needs to have the same *shape* as the actual module. Change:

```
jest.mock("pg", () => {
  return {
    query: jest
      .fn()
      .mockReturnValueOnce('one')
      .mockReturnValueOnce('two'),
  };
});
```

...to:

```
jest.mock("pg", () => ({
  Client: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    query: jest.fn()
      .mockReturnValueOnce('one')
      .mockReturnValueOnce('two')
  }))
}));
```

Comment: Thanks Jacob! What I learnt was that 1. The mock implementation must be an object with what we're importing as the keys. 2. the Constructor, fairly obviously in retrospect, should be a function.